# install libopenjpeg5 libavcodec56 librtmp1

Tags: 14.04, apt, software-installation, aptitude

I want to install the above mentioned packages as it is required for `cmus` installation as mentioned in this post

http://www.shuangrimu.com/25/

But I cannot find them in my system nor the PPA,I have searched for about 2 hours.

Any PPA to install this packages would be great..Thanks

Comment: your link is for `debian` you can directly install cmus on ubuntu

Comment: @Ravan : Sorry,but that did not help my answer at the time.I got it solved another way and thought of posting it but I forgot to.Now I have to mine the solution! :3

Comment: no problem--please post your answer,that might be useful to others :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, install [libopenjpeg5](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libopenjpeg5) [libavcodec56](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libavcodec56) [librtmp1](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=librtmp1) are not available for Ubuntu 14.04.

But if you want to install `cums` in 14.04, you have to [enable universe repository](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository) first and then:

```
sudo apt-get update    
sudo apt-get install cmus
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install **cmus**:

Open a terminal and run the following command:

`sudo apt-get install cmus`

In case your package manager doesn’t provide a current version of cmus,
 you can get it by adding the mc3man PPA to your repositories.

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/aqua-tests
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cmus
```

**Note**:
**libopenjpeg5** is available in Ubuntu - 
**libavcodec56** and **librtmp1** are not available.

Reference [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=trusty&section=all&arch=any&keywords=librtmp1&searchon=all)

Comment: I am trying to install cmus from github since I can get the latest version with all the fixes and all

Comment: @5udo I tried those steps and that is correct ppa for 14.04(Thanks to @A.B) .Surely you will get latest version with no errors.